# Отправка сообщений себе Бот aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Можно ли сделать так что бы если кто то писал боту, то сообщение отправлялось и ко мне в лс?

Comment: да, можно. в хендлере на сообщение добавить пересылку отлавливаемого сообщения